# ARP population from python script doesn't work

Tags: python, networking, nmap

I'm trying to get the IP of a device in my network (of which I know the MAC) by populating the ARP cache and reading from it:

```
def getIP(mac):
    os.system("nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 >/dev/null")
    ip_line = sub.getoutput("ip n | grep "+ mac)
    if ip_line == '':
        return ''
    else:
        return ip_line.split()[0]
```

The command that invokes nmap however doesn't seem to populate the arp cache, since it stays empty. When I do the nmap command manually it works.

I have already tried replacing os.system with

```
cp = sub.run(["nmap", "-sP", "192.168.1.0/24", ">/dev/null"])
```

This doesn't make a difference though.

Comment: how do you read the arp cache?

Comment: @Nullman I use ip -n. When I run this command outside of the script I also see that the script didn't populate the cache.

Comment: i think what ever nmap does doesnt seem to affect the system as a whole, so either run your `ip -n` in the same subprocess as `nmap` or try adding `shell=True` to your `sub.run`(but this may not work)

Comment: @Nullman Thank you. Adding shell=True did not make a difference. However, adding **--send-ip** in the nmap command did the trick. I can't explain however why it worked without it when run from a shell...

Comment: since this is pretty niche, I recommend you write what you did as an answer to your own question and mark that as the correct answer, help the next person to get stuck on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem eventaully had nothing to do with the Python code.

nmap -sP usually sends ICMP-echo-requests to all IPs in the specified network. 
There is one exception though mentioned in the documentation:

> When a privileged user tries to scan targets on a local ethernet network, ARP requests >are used unless --send-ip was specified.

This also leads to the fact that whenever the command is sent as sudo (as in my case), the ARP cache is not populated unless --send-ip is appended.